# JavaScript UI Toolkit/Framework for Photoshop-like Single-View-App

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I'm searching for JavaScript framework that facilitates the creation of a relatively rich user interface that's in principle similar to Photoshop, although less complex.
By that i mean for example:

- Resizable side bars with different panels.
- In each panel different options can be set.
- One or multiple large centered viewports with which the user can interact.
- Top menu bars with entries such as "File > New File..."

After searching for half a day I'm kind of confused since there are so many frameworks/toolkits/libraries etc. Angular, Ember, Backbone etc. are often mentioned, but I'm not so sure if that's what I need.

The framework(s) should be free.